# boundary limit conditions in 3D water surface simulation

Tags: water, simulations, boundary-conditions

As is discused on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073/Interactive-water-effect) post, taking some assumptions, the water surface can be simulated by a discrete aproximation of a grid of heights using this formula

[image]

Where:

**HT** is the new height grid

**HT-1** is the grid mapped in the previous step of the simulation

**N** is a damping factor

The 2D simulation works pretty well. I want now to move to 3D, but I'm concerned about the bundary limit conditions.

Unless I'm missing something, the document doesn't explain how to calculate the height on the limits, where there is no **x+1** or **x-1**.

I could mirror the point on the other site as if the boundaries were mirrors, but I'm not sure.

The following image depicts what's described above

[image]

Comment: The [following](http://postimage.org/image/egz5qz3jd/) depicts what is described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want your simulation to behave.

You seem to be describing what's called Periodic boundary conditions.

You might want to extrapolate and use those values in the place of your unknown values.

Comment: As described [here](http://isaacs.sourceforge.net/phys/pbc.html), Periodic Boundary Conditions woud cause a particle to pass through the boundaries an reapear on the oposite side, moving in the same direction. I would rather want that particle, or wave in my case, to be reflected back, as a result the wave would move in the opposite direction

Comment: I added an image as a comment to the question

Comment: Reflection from a SOFT boundary [here](http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/reflect/reflect.html) is what you want. You need to solve so the derivative is zero at the boundaries. Try to set your x+1 and x-1 to x. If that's not good enough, you need to re-discretize for the boundaries.

Comment: Thanks, ti realy helped me to clarify. It's as if the area below the curve remains a constant, so when the wave reaches the boundary it increases its magnitude. In which case, a good aproximation could be to make x-1 = x on the left boundary and x+1 = x on the right one, but not both, as the wave peak would be very high.

Comment: Hard boundaries is withouth a doubt the easiest to implement. At every timestep you set the boundary to some constant value, for example to zero. This produces reflections like in your picture. Soft boundaries are a little more realistic since the height of a water surface obeys soft b.c. but hard b.c. show about the same effects.